# Access values in embedded flow?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, visual-workflow

I've written an aura component that dynamically creates a child component.

This child component has an embedded flow as discussed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm).

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="flowComponent" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
<aura:handler event="c:flowFinished" action="{!c.destroyComponent}"/>
<div class='body-container'>
    <lightning:button variant="base" label="Start Flow" title="Click to launch flow" onclick="{! c.startFlow }"/>
      <div aura:id="flow-component-container" class="flow-component-container">
          <div aura:id="flow-component" id="flow">
              {!v.flowComponent}
          </div>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Is there any way, from the aura component controller, to access fields in the flow?
No luck with trying document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML.

Many thanks for any advice.

** re Anutej's comment - there's no guarantee the user will trigger the onStatusChange event (which would give me access to output variables from the flow).

Comment: Is it that you are trying to access the values being returned if that is the case then in the same article there is a link explaining on how to "Reference Flow Output Variable Values in a Wrapper Aura Component" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_inputs_get.htm can you try checking this?

Comment: Thanks- should have mentioned there's no guarantee they'll trigger that onStatusChange event, so may not get the chance to access the output variables.